# How to reset and shuffle a "next" iterator?

Tags: python, iterator

I have a function that generates numbers from -180 to 180:

```
all_angles = list(range(-180,180))
random.shuffle(all_angles)
next_angle = iter(all_angles)
```

The issue is that it stops generating after 360 (which makes sense since it's from -180 to 180):

```
n_list = []
for i in range(1000):
    n_list.append(next(next_angle))
print(len(n_list))
>>> 360 # currently it only prints 360
```

How can I reset it and shuffle it once it goes over all of the 360 values? So the above `for loop` will generate 360 shuffled numbers, reset after it goes over all the 360 values (each appearing only once), and generate another set of 360 values, and so on.

Comment: May try to re-init the iterator- that's one option.

Comment: Did you want to repeat the shuffled values or reshuffle?

Comment: Do you really want *that*, or do you just want 1000 random choices from those 360 values?

Comment: @tdelaney reshuffle

Comment: @KellyBundy I don't want 1000 random choices. I want the list to be reshuffled and regenerated when the values are over (i.e., went over all 360 of them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generator endlessly shuffling and yielding:

```
def endless_shuffling(iterable):
    values = list(iterable)
    while True:
        random.shuffle(values)
        yield from values
```

Instead of your `iter(all_angles)`, use `endless_shuffling(all_angles)` (and remove your own other shuffling).

One way to then get your list:

```
random_angles = endless_shuffling(range(-180, 180))
n_list = list(islice(random_angles, 1000))
```

If you give it an empty iterable and ask it for a value, it'll "hang", so either don't do that or guard against that case (e.g., with an extra `if values:` or with `while values:`).

I also tried a faster way to iterate than sending every value through a generator, but the shuffling dominates so it doesn't make a big difference:

```
with shuffling:
448.3 ms  endless_shuffling1
426.7 ms  endless_shuffling2

without shuffling:
 26.4 ms  endless_shuffling1
  5.1 ms  endless_shuffling2
```

Full code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLLboMwELzzFXupsCMShUStUqT8RW9thZxgh5WMQbZpkq@nfkCo0vTQlRDWzu7MeNfd1dat2u46PQxCtw1opir3w6ZrtQVT90JIngQILde2baWZ0GPNUGWARuJxrLHYcLRTQcUF66UtfVYDMwFOEpcGrirJjSmjAqpTTjw/O0hOiwRcfDHZcwN7kGjsDAbsXKPk8KZ7Hmt9jF5J7KO3/BW5rCC4i9AfBjb/MaC57bWKE1h57nLCQyG5qUvWHCpW3LuDVo/82a30/TMcKU0S0aujV/49peyBcVfv6ASggtAY7XcalSWLuB0iSMoOx5RmsMmDgutA3@EWfuLkZbzzIyIfdu3c@O2RebCKX9xYJvrIs8x368x91Am9hsggX4egc2e0lj49r3IBjYEUnoCQSA9LJ0ZhATnfOhKxKkvFGl6W9Met4hmdU9jvYVPcM5/RPet@er9uRsWHSmd9v/9pIRc6dwcGZswwfAM)):

```
from random import shuffle
from itertools import chain, islice
from timeit import default_timer as time

def endless_shuffling1(iterable):
    values = list(iterable)
    while True:
        shuffle(values)
        yield from values

def endless_shuffling2(iterable):
    values = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(iter(
        lambda: shuffle(values) or values,
        []
    ))

funcs = endless_shuffling1, endless_shuffling2

for f in funcs:
    print(*islice(f('abc'), 21))

for i in range(6):
    for f in funcs:
        t0 = time()
        next(islice(f(range(-180,180)), 999999, 1000000))
        print('%5.1f ms ' % ((time() - t0) * 1e3), f.__name__)
    print()
    if i == 2:
        print('without shuffling:\n')
        def shuffle(x):
            pass
```

Comment: You'll need to handle the case of an empty sequence or it will hang.

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah, I realized that after writing the second solution (since that one covers that case). With normal usage (including theirs) it doesn't matter, but I added a bit about it now.

Comment: For great details and timing info. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It re-shuffles the list if it recieves an error while calling `next`:

```py
import random
all_angles = list(range(-180,180))
random.shuffle(all_angles)
next_angle = iter(all_angles)
n_list = []
for i in range(1000):
    try:
        n_list.append(next(next_angle))
    except StopIteration:
        random.shuffle(all_angles)
        next_angle = iter(all_angles)
        n_list.append(next(next_angle))
print(len(n_list)) # 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reshuffle after reaching the end, I don't know of a standard tool that will do that. But you can write your own iterable instead.

```
import random

class Shuffler:

    def __init__(self, sequence):
        self.collection = list(sequence)
        self.reshuffle()

    def reshuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.collection)
        self.c_iter = iter(self.collection)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if not self.collection:
            raise StopIteration
        while True:
            try:
                return next(self.c_iter)
            except StopIteration:
                self.reshuffle()

all_angles = list(range(-180,180))
shuffler = Shuffler(all_angles)
next_angle = iter(shuffler)

n_list = []
for i in range(1000):
    n_list.append(next(next_angle))
print(len(n_list)
```

Comment: Oops, meant `cycle`.

Comment: Reworked with a reset on each cycle.